# Best way to cache statistics that don't change often

Tags: django, django-admin

I am writing a django app and as part of the job I need to crunch some data and generate statistics and serve them on a RESTful API. The statistics don't change that often, however when the statistics do change, the next request needs to serve the most up to date request. What I am currently doing is using a caching mechanism like django-redis to store the statistics and when a request is made, the view calls the cache client and serve its content. What I would prefer is a caching mechanism that prevents my view from ever being called and also provides up to date content. Is there such away (django plugin) that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to use a 'reverse proxy cache' such as Nginx or Varnish.

Basically when a request would be made to your Django application, it would first pass through your proxy cache.  The proxy cache would check to see if the request is available in the cache, and if so, it would serve the response from cache.  If the request isn't in the cache, it would hand the request off to django to process te request and issue a response.  The response would then pass back through the proxy cache and set the contents of the response into cache so that subsequent requests use the response from the cache.

Invalidating items in the cache per a write through policy as updating an item in the database could accomplished by issuing a cache purge command that is specific to the reverse proxy cache server that you have installed.